# Adding percentage of state to progress bar in blade

Tags: php, laravel, progress-bar, laravel-blade, percentage

```
<div class="progress-bar bg-progress progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{($val->profit*100)/$pp}}%;"></div>
```

How I can add percentage of state to this progress bar?

Comment: Your issue is not urgent... Please don't make it sound like an emergency. Beyond that, what's wrong with your code? What errors are you getting? Why isn't your code working? You need to explain your problem better... You don't have a clear problem, so we can't provide a solution. Please edit your question to be explain what the problem is.

Comment: this may point you in the right direction. TL;DR  use ajax, https://www.webslesson.info/2019/06/laravel-58-tutorial-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-ajax.html